# FireFox in14.04 on a 32 bit mechine? It will not run any videos.

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I have been fighting this for weeks it seems. Installing with the Software Centre fails. I had a command line last week that got Firefox to run most videos. But a major crash killed all my documents. Now another clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 and the same stuff is still happening. In FaceBook Chromium and FireFox will not start videos or run the games.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Flash player from the rpm fusion repository to play videos in your browser.

To get Flash up and running, open a new Terminal window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and copy paste the following lines :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin

This will install pepper flash(google chrome's flash player) to firefox.

If Firefox was running when you installed it, you will have to restart Firefox for changes to take place.

If that doesn't work, copy paste the following :

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
`sudo apt-get update`

Installing this package will pull in support for MP3 playback and decoding, support for various other audio formats (GStreamer plugins), Microsoft fonts, Flash plugin, LAME (to create compressed audio files), and DVD playback.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is to old a machine and not enough RAM. I dropped back to 12.04.5 and dumped Chromium for Google Chrome. Now back to things working reasonably well.